# Is there any function to compare a string with two regular expressions at a time in php

Tags: php, regex

I found `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` but these will work with only one regular expression at a time.

```
function match(){
    $pattern = array(
        '/^\-?\+?[0-9e1-9]+$/',
        '/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9 ]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/'
    );
    $string = '234';
    $pattern_mod = import(",",$pattern);
    preg_match($pattern_mod ,$string);
```

this is what i want to do

Comment: What do the regex patterns look like? Perhaps you can simply do it in one :)

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example of what you'd like to do?  Make up a function name, put in the two regexes you'd like to use, and describe using words and code what you would like to see happen.  PeeHaa is almost certainly right in that what you're doing can probably be done using a single regex, but we can't be sure until you show us what you're *actually* trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex lookahead in which a subject will first try to match foo and them try to match bar.
Like so:

```
$regexPass='/^(?=((.*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*)|(.*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*)))(.{6,})$/';
```

The regex above says that it must match the first expression  `((.*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*)|(.*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*)))` in this case alphanumerical with at least one number and one leter, AND THEM matching at least 6 digits.

In a simpler way you could match foo and them have a n on the end

```
$regexPass='/^(?=.\*foo.\*)(.\*n)$/';
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've "decrypted" correctly your question, I suppose that you have *simply* to use `and` (if have to match both),`or`(if have to match at least one) operators with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` php function.
 This is programming baby :)

Like this

```
$string='myString';

if( (preg_match(pattern,$string) and (preg_match(otherPattern,$string) )
{
 //do things
 [...]
}

or

if( (preg_match(pattern,$string) or (preg_match(otherPattern,$string) )
{
 //do things
 [...]
}
```

Where `pattern` and `otherPattern` are your regexp patterns

Comment: please add the documentation and/or a code example to show us exactly what you mean. Then I will upvote it :)

Comment: but unfortunately i am getting pattern as an array if((preg_match($pattern[],$string){//some code} i don't want to use for loop

Comment: @DonCallisto Promise is promise. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

I have two option, you can use any one fits your need (i am using and condition for just an example)-

1)

```
$subject = "abcdef";<br />
$pattern = '/^def/'; <br />
$result = preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3)); <br/>
$result1 = preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice."); <br />
echo ($result && $result1)?"true" :"false"
```

2)

```
 echo (preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3)) && preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice."))?"true" :"false";
```

Though both are almost same lines but the way of code is different, choose one that fits your taste.